# distance between two disjoint compact subsets in a metric space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be nonempty disjoint compact subsets in a metric space $(Z,d)$. Define $d(X,Y):=\inf \{d(x,y): x\in X, y\in Y\}$.

How can I show that there exist $x_0\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$ such that $d(x_0,y_0)=d(X,Y)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Show that $X \times Y$ is compact and that the distance function $d \colon X \times Y \to \mathbf{R}$ is continuous. Therefore it attains its minimum somewhere.

Comment: How do you know the distance function $d$ is continuous?

Comment: I suppose a proof would use the fact that the topology of $X \times Y$ can be metrized in a convenient way, such as by $d_{X \times Y}((x,y),(x',y')) = d_Z(x'x') + d_Z(y,y')$. For that metric on $X \times Y$, the function $d$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition, namely, $|d(x',y') - d(x,y)| \leq d_{X \times Y}((x,y),(x',y'))$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n \in X, y_n \in Y$ such that $d(x_n,y_n) \to d(X,Y)$. Since $X,Y$ are compact, there are points $x \in X, y \in Y$ and subsequences $x_{n_k} \to x, y_{n_k} \to y$.

We have $d(x,y) \le d(x,x_{n_k}) + d(x_{n_k}, y_{n_k}) + d( y_{n_k}, y)$, from which it follows that $d(x,y) \le \lim_{k \to \infty} d(x_{n_k}, y_{n_k}) = d(X,Y)$.

Comment: where will $d(x,y)\geq d(X,Y)$ come from?

Comment: Well, by definition of $d(X,Y)$, we have $d(X,Y) \le d(a,b)$ for all $a \in X, b \in Y$.